# Selecting User Object from the api Reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am recently Learning redux tool kit & I faced the following problem:

I am trying to select user object from login endpoint which is defined on apiSlice created using createApi, I am injecting the endpoints in a different file:

**userSlice.ts**

```
import { apiSlice } from "../api/apiSlice";
interface User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  token: string;
}
export const userSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    login: builder.mutation<Response, LoginRequestData >({
      query: (user) => ({
        url: '/auth/login',
        method: 'POST',
        body: user,
      })
    })
    })
  }),
});
export const { useLoginMutation , useRegisterMutation } = userSlice ;
export const selectUser = userSlice.endpoints.login.select ;
```

What I tried:

**Login.ts**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useLoginMutation } from '../../features/auth/userSlice';
import { selectUser } from '../../features/auth/userSlice';
const Login = () => {
     // what I tried 
     // first try:
     const user = useSelector( state => selectUser(state)?.user ) ;
     // second 
     const user = useSelector( state => selectUser(state) ) ;
     // both of them printed the same function down there
     // third 
     const user = useSelector( state => state.api.endpoints.login.user ) ;// no endpoints property on api  so it is printing undefined 
     console.log(user) ;
    return (
        ....
    ) ;
}
export default Login ;
```

I am getting this in the console:

```
ƒ memoized() {
    var value = cache.get(arguments);
    if (value === NOT_FOUND) {
      value = func.apply(null, arguments);
      if (resultEqualityCheck) {
        var entries = cache.getEntries();…
```